# foreach loop with XML root node data

Tags: xslt

While using the XSLT, I got a problem with a foreach loop with XML root node data.

From below XML, I need to extract an additional HI segment( with BF13 and BF14 values) only if there is a  DiagnosisPosition="BF13|14"

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <ns0:Diagnosis DiagnosisPosition="BF01|02" CodeList="BF" DiagnosisCode="1" PresentOnAdmission="Y" LCR_CD="" />
    <ns0:Diagnosis DiagnosisPosition="BF01|02" CodeList="BF" DiagnosisCode="5" PresentOnAdmission="Y" LCR_CD="" />
    <ns0:Diagnosis DiagnosisPosition="BF02|03" CodeList="BF" DiagnosisCode="12" PresentOnAdmission="" LCR_CD="" />
    <ns0:Diagnosis DiagnosisPosition="BF13|14" CodeList="BF" DiagnosisCode="13" PresentOnAdmission="Y" LCR_CD="" />
    <ns0:Diagnosis DiagnosisPosition="BF14|15" CodeList="BF" DiagnosisCode="14" PresentOnAdmission="Y" LCR_CD="" />
</root>
```

XSLT used:

```
<xsl:variable name="var:v334" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring(string(s0:Diagnosis/@DiagnosisPosition) , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;4&quot;)" />    
<xsl:variable name="var:v335" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v334) ,&quot;BF13&quot; )" />    
<xsl:if test="$var:v335">
    <xsl:for-each select="s0:Diagnosis">
        <xsl:variable name="var:v33611" select="string(@DiagnosisPosition)" />
        <xsl:variable name="var:v33711" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring($var:v33611 , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;4&quot;)" />
        <xsl:variable name="var:v33811" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v33711) , &quot;BF13&quot;)" />            
        <xsl:if test="$var:v33811">                
            <ns0:HI_OtherDiagnosisInformation>
                <xsl:for-each select="s0:Diagnosis">
                    For each loop is not working. Scope of this foreach loop is lost and goes to the root foreach loop.                        
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v336" select="string(@DiagnosisPosition)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v337" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring($var:v336 , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;4&quot;)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v338" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v337) , &quot;BF13&quot;)" />
                    <xsl:if test="$var:v338">
                        --Writing values of CodeList and Diagnosis codes
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v345" select="string(@DiagnosisPosition)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v346" select="userCSharp:StringSubstring($var:v345 , &quot;1&quot; , &quot;4&quot;)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="var:v347" select="userCSharp:LogicalEq(string($var:v346) , &quot;BF14&quot;)" />
                    <xsl:if test="$var:v347">
                        --Writing values of CodeList and Diagnosis codes
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ns0:HI_OtherDiagnosisInformation>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

I just need to extract an additional HI segment only when there is a BF13, BF14 elements else no HI segment.

I tried lots of ways but unable to get it to work and need some help/suggestions.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you and looking forward for responses.

Comment: I added a `<root>` tag to your XML.

Comment: Your given code samples are not even remotely complete. Try learning how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @zx485 - I have a feeling the XML was a snippet as we need namespace declaration in root. OP is giving us a snippet too of XSLT.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This many `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:if` is an attempt at a solution to another problem you are not asking. What is your overall goal?

Comment: What is this "HI Segment" that you are referring to? There is no "HI Segment" in the XML source you have provided. Also, "BF", "13" and "14" are values of attributes, and not elements. Please modify your question to make it complete. Also, add the final output that you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **realy** need two nested loops, both running through all `Diagnosis` elements,
then the inner loop should have the form:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../ns0:Diagnosis">
```

Apparently you forgot that the current element within a loop (`.`) is each element
from the sequence stated in the `select` clause.

I think hovewer, that you do not need the inner loop.

You wrote that you need to exctract additional information for certain `Diagnosis`
elements, only if their `DiagnosisPosition` starts with either *BF13* or *BF14*.

So maybe a single loop will be sufficient?

Instead of the inner loop you should:

- Read `DiagnosisPosition` value (once only, in your example you read it twice, under 2 different variables).
- Put `<xsl:if ...>` checking whether this value starts with *BF13* or *BF14*.
- Place additional output within this `if`.

Or maybe this additional segment of output data is to be output if **either** "number" (chars 3-4 or 6-7 from `DiagnosisPosition`, (2 chars before or after "|")) is 13 or 14?

In that case change the `test` condition accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.